# What's the manga with a exiled former sage?

Tags: story-identification, manga

When I first read this it was only a chapter or two that was out.

Story goes a former sage/hero who looks like a child, lives in some mansion in the middle of nowhere with 4 maids who are some type of monster or demon. Some guy tries to rob the place with his old magic sword that's how you find out he is the former hero/sage who defeated the demon king or something like that.

it is not an isekai! The robber guy (just some scrub who dies to show who the MC and his minter maids really are) stole the sword. The sword originally belonged to the former hero/sage.

I read it on m.manganelo.com, the manga had a more serious tone to it like a Seinen, the MC was living in exile with the monster/demon maids. I am not really sure what else I can add since it was only 2 chapters released when I read it.

Comment: Just because it's really common, was this an *isekai* novel where the protagonist is actually someone from our Earth? And is it the guy robbing it who owns the sword, or the former sage/hero?

Comment: I should also point you to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1, which gives some pointers on details that you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Ah no sorry I forgot to say it is not an isekai! The robber guy (just some scrub who dies to show who the MC and his minter maids really are) stole the sword. The sword originally belonged to the former hero/sage.

Comment: Did you check out that link with questions to help elicit more details?

Comment: I read it on https://m.manganelo.com/, the manga had a more serious tone to it like a Seinen, the MC was living in exile with the monster/demon maids. I am not really sure what else I can add since it was only 2 chapters released when I read it.

Comment: Not just putting the info in the thread? I can just add in the main post what I added here if that is the case.

Comment: You'd have to edit the post to bump it yes, comments do not bump a post.

Answer (score 2):

Since Guest hasn't elaborated on his answer, *[Shindou Yuusa to Maid Onee-san](https://myanimelist.net/manga/123407/Shindou_Yuusha_to_Maid_Oneesan)* does match.

[image: Front cover of Shindou Yuusa to Maid Onee-san]

> After defeating the Demon King and saving the world, Shion was exiled to the border. Here, the strongest Hero enjoyed his slow life with 4 capable oneesan maids.

In the first chapter of the manga, it establishes that Shion did indeed defeat the Demon King, but languishes in anonymity because royals took credit for the feat. It ends with the robber confronting him.

[image: First page of the manga, establishing that the protagonist looks like a child, lives in a remote mansion, and is tended to by several maids] (click to enlarge)

In the second chapter, we see the magic sword the robber wields.

[image: The robber brandishing Meltoll, the legendary sword that controls distance.] (click to enlarge)